# How to create a macro on a condition inside a if statement

Tags: c, macros, operators, overloading

I need to iterate a `for` loop nested inside of a `while` loop for several different conditions.

The only change in the code for each statement is the comparison condition to apply.

Turns out I am copy-pasting all of the code multiple times and changing the direction of the greater-less than symbol.

for example:

```
if (direction.horizontal == UIScrollDirectionLeft) {
    int column = startColumn+1;
    while (column < maxAllowed) {
        for (int row = minRow; row < maxRow; row++) {
            repeated code
        }
        column++;
 } else {
    int column = minColumn -1;
    while (column >= 0) {
        for (int row = minRow; row < maxRow; row++) {
            repeated code
        }
        column--;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do a macro for the condition operator in order to facilitate code reuse?

I would really like something which could look like this:

```
int  startColumn = (direction.horizontal == UIScrollDirectionLeft) ? (startColumn+1) : minColumn -1;
SignOfOperator theSignInTheWhile = (direction.horizontal == UIScrollDirectionLeft) ? "<" : ">=";
int conditionToTestInWhile = (direction.horizontal == UIScrollDirectionLeft) ? maxAllowed : 0;

while(startColumn,theSignInTheWhile,conditionToTestInWhile) {
  // repeated code
}
```

I have another 4 cases like the one above...

Comment: Why not use a pointer to a comparison function?

Comment: The function needs to return a > or <= symbol. The comparison is done in the code I already have

Comment: No, the function would *do* the comparison; like `int gt(int l, int r) { return l>r; } int (*cmpFuncPtr)(int, int) = gt; int main() { while( cmpFuncPtr(1, 2) ) ; }` Didn't test this but should be an infinite loop with minor modifications. Similarily define functions for less or equal etc. and switch the function pointer dynamically to one of them, depending on what you need.

Comment: Just make `repeated code` -> `repeatedCode()` ie, make it a function. Choosing the direction of iteration with a macro will make your code very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You only need the loop code once. Just change the step value and terminating value. For example:

```
int start_column, end_column, column_step;
   :
switch (direction.horizontal) {
  case UIScrollDirectionLeft:
    column = start_column + 1;
    column_step = 1;
    end_column = max_allowed;
    break;
  case UIScrollDirectionRight:
    column = min_column - 1;
    column_step = -1;
    end_column = -1;
    break;
  :
}
while (column != end_column) {
  for (int row = minRow; row < maxRow; row++) {
    repeated_code();
  }
  column += column_step;
}
```

Comment: I like this one. I didn't think about changing the step to negative. I will try to change the condition and see if it can work for me :)

Comment: This one is the solution, but consider making `repeatedCode()` a function, that way it will be clearer what the code does.